# Bootstrap Dropdown Opens Downward - How To Disable?

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I am having trouble setting up my main navigation menu on my website in development: http://c.tapc.net/

I have some custom jquery code to help open the second tier menus to the right (I am using Bootstrap):

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).fadeIn();

    }, function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).fadeOut();

});

$('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function() {

    location.href = this.href;

});

});
```

What is wrong:
When hovering in between the links in the main navigation menu, the menus are opening downward.  What are some ways I can disable the menus from opening downward?  I only want them to open to the right. (that is working)

Edit: I should also mention that it only does this in Firefox. (Safari, Internet Explorer - not tested)  It does not do this in Chrome.

[See example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTHMX.jpg)